# Creating multiple Actors and referencing them

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am looking at an Akka example built with the Play Framework for a web based chatroom. The example in this case, only has one room and gets instantiated with the following:

```
val room = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ChatRoom])
```

I want to expand this example and have multiple chat rooms available instead of just one. A user can provide a string, which can be a chatroom "name", and that would create a new chatroom. Anyone that tries to join this chatroom would share a broadcast with each other, but not with people in another chatroom. Very similar to IRC.

My questions are the following:

1: How do I create a ChatRoom with a unique name if one does not already exist?
2: How can I check if the existing ChatRoom exists and get a reference to it?

The chatroom name will come via either the URL or a query parameter, that part will be trivial. I'm just not entirely sure how to uniquely identify the Akka ChatRoom and later retrieve that Actor by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find your answer in this document: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

Every actor in the system has a path associated with it, which is very similar to paths in operating systems.
Example : `akka://my-sys/user/service-a/worker1`
This is a purely local path and `worker1` is the name that you would give to the actor when you create it.

You can name your actor when you create it like this:
context.actorOf(Props[ChatRoom], name = "chatroom1")

If you know the path to an actor you can get a reference to it using, `context.actorSelection("akka://my-sys/user/service-a/chatroom1")`

However when you do a `context.actorOf` it will return an `ActorRef` which is a reference to the actor. So another solution would be to store these `ActorRef`'s and look them up by name when you need them.

That said it's always better to work with actorRef's rather than actorSelection since an actorRef is tied to the lifecycle of an actor whereas actorSelection is associated with it just a reference path. ActorSelection's are useful in cases where you are not the one creating the actor and so you do not have it's reference all you know is it's name, then you can lookup them up.

Although once you have an actorSelection you can get an `ActorRef` by querying the actor using `ActorIdentity` message.